# SpriteBuilder timeline autoplay animation not running

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, spritebuilder

I am trying to understand **SpriteBuilder**.

I am facing problem of autoplay animation; it behaves strangely. I am sure I am missing some steps.

It is running in one case while in other when I load the **.ccb** file it is not running.

How can I track why autoplay animation is not running in **.cbb** file when I load it? What am I doing wrong?

And in the same way, the code of

`[self.animationManager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"WaitingForOpponent"];`

is also not working in the same way. though it works some time.

**EDIT**

Actually, I found it; it stops working when I get invitation via Game Centre for playing game. In short, if I get **UIAlertView** from Game Centre all animations of sprite builder stops working.
But I don't know how to tackle that situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i got the answer how you can achieve it, actually when you get Game centre Push Notification **cocos2d: animation stopped
** message 
and after that you get message **cocos2d: animation started with frame interval: 4.00**.

but it is not actually starting animation

what i did in `applicationDidBecomeActive` i put that code `[super applicationDidBecomeActive:application];`
 and it solved my problem :)